# Error code: ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, dns, internet-explorer

I get the error code: `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` whenever I try to go to http://reddit.com on my computer.

So far I have tried:

- setting my static DNS server to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
- executing `netsh winsock reset` on the command prompt then restarting my computer.

I can't access Reddit on any internet browser.

Comment: Where are you trying to access reddit from (location)? Also, in command prompt try `ipconfig /flushdns` and try again

Comment: Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` from the command prompt?

Comment: Also try `nslookup google.com` and `nslookup reddit.com`.

Comment: You could also run `ipconfig /flushdns` from an elevated command prompt (run as administrator). Maybe there's something weird in your DNS cache.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: just reddit? you can use all other webpages?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error for every site you visit, it's probably a DNS issue on your computer. Some ISPs might block custom DNS servers such as Google's 8.8.8.8.

If you're getting this error on a specific site, the DNS servers for that domain might be down.

Answer (score -1):

I get these a lot at work. Usually this is because the router (actually the dns service) is dying. Resetting it will help for the short term. Your best bet is to replace the router though.

I've also heard rumors that this can happen with old routers when using IPv6, but have never seen this fix the problem.